# Does the C/C++ ternary operator actually have the same precedence as assignment operators?

Tags: c++, c, ternary-operator, operator-precedence

Almost all C/C++ operator precedence tables I have consulted list the ternary conditional operator as having higher precedence than the assignment operators. There are a few tables, however, such as the one on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence), and the one at [operator-precedence.com](http://cpp.operator-precedence.com/), that place them on the same precedence level. Which is it, higher or same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer for C++ is that `?:` and `=` have the same precedence. Yes, almost every C++ operator precedence table out there is wrong.

In C it doesn't matter whether `?:` is higher than `=` or not, because in C the `?:` operator is not allowed to evaluate to an l-value, which is what it would have to do if precedence were to influence the behavior (given that they are already RTL associative). See the discussion under Luchian Crigore's answer for example.

Perhaps this error is so widespread because early C++ operator precedence tables may have been copied and extended from C tables. And perhaps the error has persisted because the only counterexample - expressions of the form `a?b:c=d` - are rarely used. Perhaps.

Answer (score 12):

In the C++ grammar,

```
assignment-expression:
    conditional-expression
    logical-or-expression assignment-operator initializer-clause
    throw-expression

conditional-expression:
    logical-or-expression
    logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression

initializer-clause:
    assignment-expression
    braced-init-list
```

could be combined to

```
assignment-expression:
    logical-or-expression
    logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
    logical-or-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression
    logical-or-expression assignment-operator initializer-clause
    throw-expression
```

If only looking at `=` and `?:`, and if ignoring the inner expression between `?` and `:`, this clearly gives `?:` and `=` the exact same precedence.

This is different from the C grammar, in which neither `?:`'s left nor its right operand can have an assignment operator as its topmost operator.

```
assignment-expression:
    conditional-expression
    unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression

conditional-expression:
    logical-OR-expression
    logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

So for C, it makes sense to give them different precedence levels.

That said, precedence levels are only an approximation of what the standard actually says, there will be cases for any precedence levels you choose that show the levels to be misleading or just plain wrong. Depending on your interpretation, the inner expression of `?:` may be one of them, it is for me.

Comment: In your example the assignment is a sub-expression of the containing ternary operator expression. So, precedence doesn't exactly apply.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Yes, and in `a = b ? c : d`, `b ? c : d` is a sub-expression of the containing assignment expression, yet neither is specified with parentheses.

Comment: @hvd nope, in `a = b`, `b` is an initializer expression independent of `=` (once the precedence has been established)

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin You're thinking of `int a = b;`. `a = b;` is an ordinary assignment-expression, there is no initialisation.

Comment: Also, I think this is different in C and C++ -- in C, `a = b ? c : d` will be equivalent to `(a = b) ? c : d`.

Comment: @avakar No, that means the same thing in C as it does in C++. What is different is `a ? b : c = d`, but I avoided that in my answer :)

Comment: @hvd How does your answer prove anything? There is only one way you could put parentheses in the expression `a ? b = c : d`, so the second example is useless. The first example just shows that `?` has higher (or same) precedence than `=`.

Comment: @hvd this looks like a completely new answer to me. Shouldn't you post it as a new answer and revert this one to preserve the relevance of the comments?

Comment: I see no need to prove myself, and this discussion is now over for me.

Answer (score 8):

You'll find that, in the standard:

#### 5 Expressions [expr]

> 58) The precedence of operators is not directly specified, but it can be derived from the syntax. (note)

This means precedence tables are inferred, not specified. As long as they behave the same, you can say that both are right. So, even if a precedence table places them as having the same precedence, or places the ternary above the assignment operator, in practice the same thing happens, because of the syntax.

Note that **associativity** plays a bigger role here (this is also derived from the syntax).

Even if you assume that they have the same precedence:

```
a = b ? c : d;
```

will be treated as `a = (b ? c : d)` because they are both **right-to-left associative**.

Comment: True, but precedence would still influence the interpretation of `a?b:c=d`. Is it `(a?b:c)=d` or is it `a?b:(c=d)`?

Comment: @IsakduPreez it groups right-to-left, so `a?b:(c=d)`. I already said associativity is more important in this case.

Comment: By saying "associativity is more important" you must be saying "they have the same precedence", right? Otherwise it would be interpreted as `(a?b:c)=d`.

Comment: @IsakduPreez you can see it as that, yes :)

Comment: It is incorrect explanation, associativity only works when precedence is the same. It cannot be "more important" or play "bigger role"