# ternary operator and assignment operator

Tags: c++, c, assignment-operator, conditional-operator, associativity

in [Does the C/C++ ternary operator actually have the same precedence as assignment operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515434/does-the-c-c-ternary-operator-actually-have-the-same-precedence-as-assignment)

Luchian Grigore's answer says that cases like

```
a ? b : c = d
```

will always be inferred as

```
a ? b : ( c = d )
```

because both = and ?: associate right to left so

in c++

```
k =  21 > 3 ? j = 12 : j = 10;
```

and

```
k = 1 > 3 ? j = 12 : j = 10;
```

both are fine.

In C

```
k = 21 > 3 ? 12 : j = 10
```

returns error

```
invalid lvalue in assignment.
```

Shouldn't above be inferred as (and return no error)

```
k=  21 > 3 ? 12 : ( j = 10 )
```

I assume now it is being grouped as

```
k = ( 21 > 3 ? 12 : j ) = 10
```

which gives error since in C(not in C++) ternary operator cannot return lvalue.
Can anyone tell me exactly how operators are grouped in this case.

Comment: I would try to avoid such curiosities and just write
if (1 > 3)
  k = j = 12
else
  k = j = 10

Comment: `a ? b : c = d` is *different* in C and in C++! It's `a ? b : (c = d)` in one and `(a ? b : c) = d` in the other.

Comment: I think it is processed as `k=(21>3?12:j=10)` actually

Comment: Rule of thumb of such situations is "unless it's completely clear at glance without chance of doubt, use () or separate subexpressions". This applies even more here due to difference in C and C++ rules. The raw assignment in ?: should not survive a review

Comment: i wont ever use such code,this is just to understand how things work.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas http://ideone.com/nbJYZn

Comment: @ZxcvMnb: That is the problem of asking C/C++ as if they are the same language. I am no expert in C, so whatever the C compiler says is probably true, but in C++ my comment stands.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas yes I agree

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the C/C++ ternary operator actually have the same precedence as assignment operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515434/does-the-c-c-ternary-operator-actually-have-the-same-precedence-as-assignment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your linked question's ([Does the C/C++ ternary operator actually have the same precedence as assignment operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515434/does-the-c-c-ternary-operator-actually-have-the-same-precedence-as-assignment)) answer by @hvd shows the answer.

The C++ and C grammars for `?:` are different.

In C++, the rightmost operand is allowed to be an assignment expression (so the compiler [greedily] treats the `=` are part of the `?:`) while in C the rightmost operand is a `conditional-expression` instead. Thus in C as soon as the compiler hits the `=` the analysis of `?:` is complete and it treats it as `k = ( 21 > 3 ? 12 : j ) = 10`.

Comment: And since 12 is not a lvalue and you'll get a compiler error when you try to compile `12 = 10`.

Comment: @Lundin I think it is about (21 > 3 ? 12 : j) not being an lvalue , so by replacing 12 by j we still get same error.

Comment: In c <br> logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression ,<br> In c++ logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression <br> So c compiler happily takes j as conditional-expression and continues.Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 0):

`k=21>3?12:(j=10)` gets evaluated as

```
if ( 21 > 3 )
    k = 12;
else
    k = ( j = 10 );
```

Since `21>3` is `true`, the else condition does not get evaluated and `j` has undefined value (or whatever value it had prior to this statement).

Comment: Sorry the question was edited. Original question ,why "k = 21 > 3 ? 12 : j = 10" is not evaluated as k = 21 > 3 ? 12 : (j = 10) in C

Comment: If you do not have parentheses around `j=10`, the left to right evaluation assigns `j` to `k` and has an additional assignment after that.  Since you have a constant (`12`) in the success case (not an lvalue), the compiler tries to parse assigning `10` to a non-lvalue and issues the error.