# lvalue required as left operand of assignment.....?

Tags: c

I'm doing my c homework..... :( using a trinomial operator(?) _oo? oo : oo

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int time1, time2, gap;
    int hour, minute;

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    printf("Enter first time: \n");
    scanf("%d", &time1);

    printf("Enter second time: \n");
    scanf("%d", &time2);

    gap = time2 - time1;

    gap > 0 ? hour = gap/100 : hour = (2400 - gap)/100;
    gap > 0 ? minute = gap%100 : minute = (2400 - gap)%100;

    print("The gap of these times: %d hours, %d minutes", hour, minute);

}
```

*gap > 0 ? gap/100 = hour : (2400 - gap)/100 = hour;*

*gap > 0 ? minute = gap%100 : minute = (2400 - gap)%100;*

These two sentences are error(lvalue required as left operand of assignment)

**The result I want**

Enter first time:
1925

Enter second time:
2358

The gap of these times: 4 hours, 33 minutes

**OR**

Enter first time:
1540

Enter second time:
1630

The gap of these times: 0 hours, 50 minutes

**OR**

Enter first time:
0730

Enter second time:
0720

The gap of these times: 23 hours, 50 minutes

Comment: It is not called a Trinomial operator.  It is the [Ternary Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Comment: @abelenky Also called "conditional operator". People call it "ternary operator" just because it happens to be the only ternary operator (take 3 arguments).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the C/C++ ternary operator actually have the same precedence as assignment operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515434/does-the-c-c-ternary-operator-actually-have-the-same-precedence-as-assignment)

Comment: Also see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406503/ternary-operator-and-assignment-operator

Comment: The `?:` operator is not a control structure and should *not* be used to emulate an `if` statement.  That's not its purpose.  abelenky's answer shows the proper usage.

Answer (score 4):

Try instead:

```
 hour   = (gap > 0) ? gap/100 : (2400 - gap)/100;
 minute = (gap > 0) ? gap%100 : (2400 - gap)%100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since both conditional expressions evaluate the same condition, it would be cleaner to combine assignments in an `if` statement:

```
if (gap > 0) {
    hour = gap/100;
    minute = gap%100;
} else {
    hour = (2400 - gap)/100;
    minute = (2400 - gap)%100;
}
```

You could further simplify this by adding a new variable:

```
int numerator = gap > 0 ? gap : 2400-gap;
hour = numerator/100;
minute = numerator%100;
```