# Why is "sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(int)" refused in a cout?

Tags: c++

Why can I write:

```cpp
bool a = sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(int);
cout << "(taille unsigned integer = integer) ? " << a;
```

But this:

```cpp
cout << "(taille unsigned integer = integer) ? " << sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(int);
```

produces a compilation error?

`Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type' (aka 'basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>') and 'unsigned long')`

Comment: Operator prededence, just add brackets

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/20767745/4117728

Comment: On top of everything - the first version is a lot easier to read and understand. Pretty obvious that you want to print a bool. Not all that clear for the second version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue of operator precedence.  The `<<` operator has higher prcedence  than `==`, so your expression is parsed as

```
(cout << "(taille unsigned integer = integer) ? " << sizeof(unsigned int)) == (sizeof(int))
```

Since the `ostream` `<<` operator overloads return the `ostream` they're called on, you're trying to compare a `std::ostream` to an `int`, and there is no such comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Due to operator precedence, it is interpreted as:

```
(cout << "? " << sizeof(unsigned int) ) == sizeof(int);
```

To solve that, add parentheses around `==`:

```
cout << "? " << (sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(int));
```