# a = a + b - (b=a); how this expression will evaluate in c language?

Tags: c

I have a question regarding operators Associative rule  **a = 10, b=20;  a = a + b - (b=a)**; according to associativity rule the expression inside parentheses will solve first like first a will assign to b and then addition will perform and then subtraction  but here a+b  is evaluating first and then the value of a is assigning to b  i don't understand this

According to me the value of **a** which is 10 will assign to **b** now **b** have 10 and then addition will perform a+b which will be 10 + 10  = 20 and then 20 - 10. = 10 will assign to **a**

but the actual output is **a = 20, b=10**
according to me **a =10,b=10**

Comment: Only tag the language of which the question is about. You have tagged C, C++ and Java. All have their own rules.

Comment: Associativity controls grouping, not order of evaluation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who defines operator precedence and associativity, and how does it relate to order of evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20767745/who-defines-operator-precedence-and-associativity-and-how-does-it-relate-to-ord)

Comment: Given `a + b - (b=a)`, consider the `a + b` is happening _at the same time_ as `(b=a)` and there is a bus conflict reading and writing `b` leading to system reboot - another form of UB.

Comment: Where did you find this code? It should never be used in real-world programs.

Comment: Also we can't just wildly remove language tags without clarification from the OP. This should just be closed as unclear, not edited.

Comment: @Lundin: OP’s title says they are asking about C, so removing the Java and C++ tags is appropriate. It is certainly not wild.

Comment: @EricPostpischil They could be translating code from Java to C for all we know.

Answer (score 2):

> a = a + b - (b=a); how this expression will evaluate in c language?

It is [not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) how this expression will evaluate in C programming language. In the `b - (b = a)` expression, there is no sequence point between assignment to `b` on the right side and use of `b` value on the left side, and the order of evaluation of arguments of the `-` minus operation is not defined. So the side effect of assigning to `b` is unsequenced with value computation of `b`.

Comment: FYI, in C 2011, the standard moved to a more sophisticated model of sequencing than just sequence points. Avoiding undefined behavior does not require a sequence point between two side effects or between a side effect and a value computation; it only requires that they be sequenced.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that the code has **undefined behavior** because `b` is both used and assigned without a sequence point between. Consequently anything is allowed to happen. Any result is valid. The program may even crash.

The C standard says that operators `+`and `-` has the same precedence with left-to-right-associativity. So for your code the C standard says that the `+` operator shall be executed before the `-` operator. However, the C standard does not specify the order of operand evaluation.

So the line of code can be executed as

```
1) temp = a + b      // temp is 30
2) b = a             // b is 20    (evaluation of right side operand for -)
3) temp = temp - b   // temp is 10
4) a = temp          // a is 10
```

but it may also be executed as

```
1) b = a             // b is 10    (evaluation of right side operand for -)
2) temp = a + b      // temp is 20
3) temp = temp - b   // temp is 10
4) a = temp          // a is 10
```

Two different results. Both valid according to the C standard due to undefined behavior.

Comment: FYI, in C 2011, the standard moved to a more sophisticated model of sequencing than just sequence points. Avoiding undefined behavior does not require a sequence point between two side effects or between a side effect and a value computation; it only requires that they be sequenced.