# Why does this C program not compile?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a=10,b;
a>=5?b=100:b=200;
printf("%d",b);
}
```

what is the error?

It works like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a=10,b;
a>=5?(b=100):(b=200);
printf("%d",b);
}
```

Why are the parentheses needed?

Comment: Try adding `\n` to your printf string.

Comment: And now it's really a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515434/does-the-c-c-ternary-operator-actually-have-the-same-precedence-as-assignment

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Leaving `main` flushes the buffer anyway.

Comment: I guess people downvote your question because you did not provide the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assignment has the lowest precedence, you want to do:

```
a >=5 ? (b=100) : (b=200);
```

---

Your original expression has the following meaning:

```
(a >= 5 ? b = 100 : b) = 200;
```

In C, ternary operator `?:` does not return an lvalue, hence it cannot assign 200 to the result of `?:`. And that would be not what you expected.

---

The operator precedence set this way so that expression:

```
b = a >= 5 ? 100 : 200;
```

Is

```
b = (a >= 5 ? 100 : 200);
```

And not

```
(b = a) >= 5 ? 100 : 200;
```

Comment: @Paul: Yes, it does. The code doesn't compile for that very reason.

Comment: @Paul The original code does not compile.

Comment: @Paul: It doesn't compile as C++ either. `main` cannot return `void` in C++.

Comment: No..i mean why do we have to use parenthesis? why does it not work without the parenthesis?

Comment: @code_starter: do you know why `1+2*3` gives a different result than `(1+2)*3`?

Comment: @code_starter I elaborated for you.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin ..Thank you,that was the answer I was looking for..sorry I can not upvote it as my reputation has reduced below 15 due to so many downvotes..don't know why so many people downvoted it.. I am a newbie

Answer (score 1):

How do you expect it to print when there is a compiler error?

Check the below code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
int a=10,b;
a>=5?(b=100):(b=200);
printf("%d",b);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`a>=5?b=100:b=200;`

could be written as:

`b=(a>=5)?100:200;`

Also, the

`printf("%d",b);`

should be
`printf("%d\n",b);`

`\n` forces the `stdout`, output buffer to flush.

Alternatively, you could also print to `stderr` which is unbuffered(in most implementations).

```
fprintf(stderr, "hello"); //will print immediately, even if \n is not there
```

Again, to print immediately you could also do:
`printf("%d\n",b);`
`fflush(stdout);`

And if you are in linux, to disable buffering entirely do: `setbuf(stdout, NULL);`

Comment: Why hasn't anybody commented on the `void main()` yet ?

Comment: @ALL No..i mean why do we have to use parenthesis? why does it not work without the parenthesis?

Comment: @code_starter: parentheses are a way in C to override the precedence of operators in a statement and also visually highlight the same. As such the statement now works something, like this: `is a>=5` . If yes initialize b with 100 else b with 200.

Comment: you are right @askmish ..my reputation has reduced to 1 because of the downvotes so I can not even upvote an answer..it sure is a discouraging trend